# Gridlayout Manager With Recycerview android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[image: Real Image]

I want to create this type of layout using Recycerview.but i am gettting some issue with it.

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(parentActivity, 2));
```

using above line ,i have display list in 2 column .but when height of some view is small then getting blank space..i want to remove that blank space.

issue screenshot:

[image: Current Screen]

Please give solution to remove that space.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Comment: @Rohit5k2 thnks but i m using recyclerview.and i want to changes on it based on gridlayout manager

Comment: This would do the job then http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

```
  sGManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager)
```

see http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Comment: thnks.its workin fine.